# Keyboard lags three seconds first use iPad only - Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, xcode7

My Keyboard lags on iPad ios8 and ios9, but was never doing it before the Xcode 7 update. Same code works fine on iphone, and second time page is loaded ipad keyboard works fine. After I press "next" to the next view controller, it takes three or four seconds to load the page because of the keyboard (I've debugged and removing this code allows page to load in less than a second). However, my view requires the keyboard be up when the page is loaded.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.firstPinField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

have tried in viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad

Is this a bug in xCode7, or does any one have an idea for me to try?

Comment: Since Xcode is just the IDE the issue might lay in the iOS 9 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard takes some time to load. Try [this library](https://github.com/mbrandonw/UIResponder-KeyboardCache), which basically just creates a hidden `UITextField`, and force keyboard to load when the app starts.

Comment: The last update on this github repository was three years ago :/ not sure this could help me.

Comment: I still use it in a current project. It's keyboard caching, like 10 lines of code that you can write yourself. Nothing to update.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by adding in main queue in view did load

Comment: This is a terrible answer - obviously I tried viewDidLoad and I mentioned this in my post.